# Winff missing root element

Tags: winff

Ubuntu 18.04

So, everything was working fine till today. I was converting files from mp4 to DNxHD for use in DaVinci resolve. My machine started acting up and the conversions slowed way down, so I rebooted and when it came back up my winff gives me this error:

```
In 'file:///home/cody/.winff/cfg.xml' (line 1 pos 1): Root element is missing.

Press OK to ignore and risk data corruption.
Press Abort to kill the program.
```

I can't find anything specific on that issue. The `cfg.xml` file is in the folder but it is just a blank file. I tried uninstalling it through synaptic and reinstalling it with no change. I tried `apt-get purge` also with reinstall and again no change. What goes in the `cfg` file? Or how do I fix this?

thanks

Comment: `mv $HOME/.winff/  $HOME/.winff.broken/` so you can see if your user config is broken ore something else.

Comment: So the cfg.xml file was in the Home/.winff folder, my issue was that it was a blank file. I did finally fix it by installing winff on a laptop I have and then copying the file from it over and no it works fine. There are like 3 or 4 lines of text in the cfg.xml file.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CONFIG>
  <unix ffmpeg="/usr/bin/ffmpeg" ffplay="/usr/bin/ffplay" terminal="/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator" termoptions="-e"/>
</CONFIG>